# How to impliment the back control button in ios 7

Tags: button, ios7, back

Can't seem to find any answers to this in the SO network.

From Apples Doc they say:

"The Back control is a chevron plus the title of the previous screen."

How do I add a chevron?

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Back Button?]

Comment: I should add I'm new to iOS development, please add detailed instructions :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html

Comment: normally the _Back_ button is handled by `UINavigationController` class, and you do not need to do anything for getting it, because it will be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code for add back button

```
UIBarButtonItem *backbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Go Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(gobackBtn)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backbtn];
```

back button action method

```
- (void)gobackBtn
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: for that you have to assign "<" image to bar button using follwing code `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:(UIImage *) style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle) target:(id) action:(SEL)]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set < sign back button then as Haresh said make one image like '<' this symbol then add this code for set this `'<'` button in left bar button

```
UIButton *btnAdd = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];

[btnAdd setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

[btnAdd setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btnAdd addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *btnAdd = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imView];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnAdd;
```

and in backButtonPressed event

```
- (void)backButtonPressed
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Thanks.